# Issue to load The Microsoft Ajax Content Delivery Network (CDN)

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

I am wonder why when use Microsoft CDN it cause problems in my site.

for example when I use :

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then my page has problem to validate the data each time I am facing with new issue...

but when I load the those js file from local as below, there is no any problem.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So what is wrong with that ?

Comment: Do you get any error message in the console window of your browser?

Comment: @Adriano no , just not working validation

Comment: Why no body answer to my question ?